# Observable in angular 2, data is not logging to the console

Tags: angularjs, angular, observable, reactivex

The following code is not logging the **data** to the console windows nor it's throwing any exceptions and Transpiler is also not showing any errors,  I'm working on **angular 2.0.0-beta.7**
I've been looking to resolve this issue since 4 hours but couldn't figure out the solution.

**app.component.ts** is below

```
import {Component} from "angular2/core";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Rx";


@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: ` 
          <input id="search" type="text" class="form-control">
          `

})

export class AppComponent {
   constructor() {
      var keyups = Observable.fromEvent($("#search"), "keyup");

       keyups.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
     }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
     <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/styles.css">
  <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
  <!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
    <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"> </script>
  <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
<script>
    System.config({
        packages: {
            app: {
                format: 'register',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
    System.import('app/boot')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
</head>

<!-- 3. Display the application -->
    <body>
     <my-app>
       Loading...
     </my-app>

    </body>
  </html>
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
  "target": "es5",
  "module": "system",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "sourceMap": true,
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "removeComments": false,
  "noImplicitAny": false
},
 "exclude": [
 "node_modules",
 "typings/main",
 "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
   "start": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
  "tsc": "tsc",
  "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
  "lite": "lite-server",
  "typings": "typings",
  "postinstall": "typings install"
  },
   "license": "ISC",
   "dependencies": {
   "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.7",
   "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
   "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
   "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
  "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
  "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
  "systemjs": "0.19.22",
  "zone.js": "0.5.15"
 },
  "devDependencies": {
   "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
   "lite-server": "^2.1.0",
  "typescript": "^1.7.5"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do use your code within the `ngAfterViewInit` method of your component instead of its constructor.

See this link for more details: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/AfterViewInit-interface.html.

You could also leverage the `ViewChild` decorator as described below:

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from "angular2/core";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Rx";


@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: ` 
          <input #search type="text" class="form-control">
          `
})
export class AppComponent {
   @ViewChild('search')
   search:ElementRef;

   ngAfterViewInit() {
      var keyups = Observable.fromEvent(this.search.nativeElement, "keyup");

       keyups.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
     }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, can you please tell me why my code didn't work? :)

Comment: You're welcome! You try to reference a DOM element before it was created (in the constructor). You need to wait for this leveraging component lifecycle hooks (the `ngAfterViewInit` one in your case). The component constructor isn't linked to this lifecycle and is called even before the component is compiled and the associated DOM created.

Answer (score 0):

Thierry's answer worked for me but shouldn't `ElementRef` also be imported?

```
import {Component, ViewChild, ElementRef} from 'angular2/core';
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to tell you that the same code works with  "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.0"

package.json

```
{
"name": "angular2-quickstart",
"version": "1.0.0",
"scripts": {
"tsc": "tsc",
"tsc:w": "tsc -w",
"lite": "lite-server",
"start": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" "
},
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
"angular2": "2.0.0-beta.0",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
"es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
"es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
"reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.0",
"systemjs": "0.19.6",
"zone.js": "0.5.10"
},
"devDependencies": {
"concurrently": "^1.0.0",
"lite-server": "^1.3.1",
"typescript": "^1.7.3"
}
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
"target": "ES5",
"module": "system",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"sourceMap": true,
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"removeComments": false,
"noImplicitAny": false
},
"exclude": [
"node_modules"
]
}
```